# Alternatives to OpenGL ES for complex animations?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am relatively new to iPhone programming, and I have a considerably complex app to develop.
This app requires animations such as burning a photo, flushing something down a toilet, etc.

Is there any way I can manage to code these animations without having to learn OpenGL ES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.  I don't believe that Quartz or Core Animation will give you acceptable frame rates for then kinds of animations you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

There's always [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), but it is unlikely you will beat OpenGL ES for performance.

Comment: I can use Core Animation for those complex animations?

Answer (score 1):

IMO this book is the leading book reference on Core Animation and they walk through some pretty impressive/complex animations: [http://www.amazon.com/Core-Animation-Mac-iPhone-Programmers/dp/1934356107/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1264529803&sr=8-2-spell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356107)

Possibly you get do what you need with some crafty coding.